# Behind the clouds

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay

**The cloud obscures three rays.  What are they?**

[image: behind_the_clouds]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Let's blow that cloud away...

> [image]
>
> The missing rays (clockwise) are **SL**, **REVI** and **WE**!

---

Each word

> Can loop round to the next, to form a new word, as shown in the sun above!

So the missing words:

> The only word that ends in 'REWOLF' is WEREWOLF, so one of the missing rays is **WE**.
>
> On the other side, we need a word that starts with 'GNAR'.
>
> The middle ray can have 'EW' added to the end to form a word, and when reversed can add on the end of the 'GNAR' suffix.
>
> So with that in mind, the missing rays are **SL**, **REVI** and **WE**, forming the following combos:
>
> GNAR-**LS**, **SL**-**IVER**, **REVI**-**EW**, and **WE**-REWOLF!
>
>
> ’LED’ and ‘L’ also work instead of SL, creating ‘GNARL(ED)’ and ‘(DE)LIVER’ too!

Comment: Nice.  I would have also accepted GNARLED, which also works within the context.

Comment: @SlowMagic oh hadn’t even noticed that one! Big fan of your style of puzzles, keep it up! Lot of fun to do :)

Comment: just GNARL works, too

Comment: @msh210 ha! An even simpler solution

Comment: @msh210 – Interesting.  Neither GNARL nor GNARLS are in my 100,000-word dictionary.  Only GNARLED, GNARLY, and GNARLIEST.

Comment: Dang!   Finally a cool puzzle I caught onto the purpose of quick, but I didn't read close enough and thought it was just 2 words so I wasted some time and couldn't figure it out so I looked at the answer :(

Comment: @JasonGoemaat I also originally thought it was 2 just from the shape of the sun, then clocked the question said three, easy mistake! I often don't read questions properly too :)

Comment: @JasonGoemaat – I posted another one for you.  Exactly the same rules.  Go here:    https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117994/behind-the-clouds-again