# Behind the clouds, again

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay

**What are the three rays obscured by the cloud?**

[image: behind_the_clouds_again]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Blowing away the cloud again reveals:

> [image]

So the missing rays are...

> **DEV**, **DEL** and **DETAI**!
>
> These form the new words ALLEV-**IATED**, **DETAI**-**LED**, **DEL**-**VED** and **DEV**-ELOP!

Comment: Please excuse the horrifically drawn sun, I only just realised how un-circular it is :P